# About Unsafe.getObjectVolatile usage

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

As known, the arrays, even when volatile, do not provide volatile semantics when reading or writing elements, concurrent accessing the k-th element of the array requires an explicit volatile read. This volatile read is performed through the `Unsafe.getObjectVolatile()`.

I want to know , only declaring one object, not array without volatile, using `Unsafe.getObjectVolatile()` to read it can get the same effect as declaring it with volatile?

Comment: Your question doesn't compile :) At least not in my brain.

Comment: [Yes](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jsr.166-concurrency/12972). If you look at the source code in the VMs, you'll see that they emit a read barrier.

Comment: Only when all writes to the field are using `putObjectVolatile`. But why do you want that? Why not simply declaring the field `volatile`?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `volatile` array.  There is no such thing as a `volatile` object.  The only thing in the Java language that can be `volatile` is a _field_.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the implementation of `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceArray`

It internally uses a `private final Object[] array` field and does fenced accesses to it through unsafe, e.g. here is the element setter:

```
public final void set(int i, E newValue) {
    unsafe.putObjectVolatile(array, checkedByteOffset(i), newValue);
}
```

Do note that the *internal and unsupported* Unsafe API will probably go away/become inaccessible with java 9, so if you want to use it prepare for some forward-porting effort once [varhandles](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/193) arrive. And/or consider implementing a fallback codepath.